# Rails: Puma server 3 not showing database queries in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I upgraded Puma to version 3. When I start the development server (`rails s -b0.0.0.0`), the console only shows the requests, not the actual database queries as before (version <= 3). I couldn't find an option for it.

**How can I see the database queries in the development console?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG` to your environments.rb

or `config.log_level = :debug` environments/development.rb

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG did the trick. Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Please add this two lines in your development.rb file which is located in config/environments/

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
```

Hope your problem will be resolved.